# pickup calls automatically in android

Tags: android

I'm new to Android. I'm looking for a way to attend incoming calls automatically. I just went through **SIPDemo** but couldn't understand much info.

Is it possible to attend call from particular number?" and "Is there any material or tutorial on this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the Answer Intent - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_ANSWER